# Changing button identifier in navigtion bar bar button

Tags: ios, swift

I know this question has been asked before and I've found two different lines of code that purport to perform a change in the identifier for a bar button item in a navigation bar.  Both compile, but neither has any effect on the identifier.  I start the program with the identifier set to a Play button, and want to change it to a Pause button.  I've run these two lines of code both in viewDidLoad() and inside

```
IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {
```

Here is the code.  Can anyone tell me why the button identifier is not changing?  And, is the rightButton/leftButton as obvious as it appears, or is there something about words in the code I don't get.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "startButton:")

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "startButton"), animated: true)
```

Here is the entire viewDidLoad, where it does not work either.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "startButton:")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to toggle button in `UINavigationBar`

In `override func viewDidLoad()` writes

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action:Selector("startButton:"))
```

and create two `@IBAction` for button

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton!) {

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "stopButton:"), animated: true)
}

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton!) {

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "startButton:"), animated: true)
}
```

@Bendrix, you can see code which I have tried [my view controller code](http://i61.tinypic.com/2vj1utd.png)
And video after run this code in simulator [app in simulator](http://tinypic.com/r/2u5gg84/8)

Comment: I tried this and it had no effect on the button.  I am curious, with two different Actions for one button, how will the system know which action to run.  I added a bool toggle so it should only execute one block of code or the other, but my question is, when you hit the button, do both blocks of code run?  In any case, this did not work.  Did you try it?  In the simplest case the single line in UEViewDidLoad should change the button identifier if it is possible to do so.  Still need help with this.

Comment: Obviously, I tried it....and here two different buttons with their respective action...just use them as your need. Or you can change button with only one action by using bool flag.

Comment: I may be confused.  Answer text says "and create two @IBAction for button", and in the comment just above, says, "two different buttons with respective action". To clarify, then, your answer above had two different buttons, both in the leftBarButtonItem position?  Can you overlay buttons like that?  Using two IBAction for one button did not work even with a toggle to theoretically transfer control back and forth.  I don't see how the compiler would know which of the IBActions to run, if you have two for one item.  If you post code for the whole solution it would help.